# Calling a function in another class with react js and react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Sorry guys, total beginner with react js here and could use some help.

I have 3 classes, an app that is just for my router, a header, and a main page.

All I want is when a button in the header is pressed, a set is called in the main page.

i dont see why something like this shouldnt work:

**mainpage:**

```
const [data, setdata] = useState([false]);

const state = () => setdata(false);
```

**header:**
`onClick={() => mainpage.setdata(true)}`

it doesn't seem like it should be complicated but obviously, this doesn't work so I would appreciate any and all advice

Comment: You need to show more code.  Are you including header in your main page?

Comment: No cause I'm including header in my app. Should it be in the main page? Also what kind of code would you like? id be happy to provide more if it helps. the project has a whole bunch of stuff that is unnecessary to the question so i would rather just write an example like i did above.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to modify/share state between sibling components, the easier approach is to move the state (useState) up to the parent component and then pass down both the state and the function to modify it, as props.

or you can use a state management library where you can dispatch actions from anywhere to modify the state.

Comment: Thanks, bro I'll look into both those options, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by the question. From my understanding you want to set a toggle function to a button. such as

```
    const [data, setData] = useState(false]);
    
      function toggle(){
    setData(!data);
  };

  return (
    <>
        <button onClick={toggle}>Toggle Subjects</button>
    </>
```

React-router is normally used in creating a Navigation Bar for your app and I am not sure how it's related to the question, please clarify.

Comment: I thought it might be related because the parent isn't the one using the set data, it's just being used with the router, but it might be irrelevant. All I'm trying to do really is change a boolean variable in another class when a button In the first class is pressed. Idk if thats helpful at all, sorry about it being unclear.

Comment: M.Samir is probably on the right track. I'd follow his advice about hoisting the state (useState) to the parent and just stay cognizant of the fact that in React, Hooks ( like useState, useEffect, etc..) can only work if you're passing them down from parent to child and/or children.